# Android Studios image display issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-image

Android Studio (Mac): 
Add images to my Drawable folder: 
I was initially trying >jpg switched to >png both show up as a "grey box".

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can resolve?  (Note: Mac user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the image. Click on the drawable folder and paste it.